# Angular slow API call

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular application with asp dot net web api. I am running the app in localhost. When I stop my web api, restart it and call the web api from angular again, the angular gets slower on first api call (api call takes time). After the first call, the other calls run at normal speed. Is there a fix to this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Who knows, that's.nit enough detail to debug.

Comment: I am getting issue of exactly what I explained. Stop Web API, start it again, on first angular call, its slower, then its get normal on other angular calls

Comment: Please show us some code. Do you make the first call synchronous?

Comment: If your API call is going all the way down to the database, this is most likely a "problem" with Entity Framework (or any other ORM framework) as the first call to it results in a lot of setup work that needs to be done, this is also called a "cold query".

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got it, its normal behavior on first call as the dll's need to be loaded on first call which causes delay.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how .net apps are built.

This is of course a bit of a guess. I assume you are starting with this project and this is not related with you having a large cache that is populated on first request ;)

You backend app (typically) is using something called dll's ([dynamicly linked libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library)). So when the API starts it doesn't really load all the code. Only the parts that it needed to start.
When you make the first call a lot of additional code is loaded into the memory. That's why there is a delay on first call. This is a standard "issue".

You shouldn't really worry about it to much at this stage. There are way of preventing this behavior in production.

One of them is "warm-up procedure" - usually linked with a health check endpoint. You just call an endpoint that loads everything that you need at startup (and then every couple of minutes for example).

This is of course a simplification.

Other approach is pre-compilation. Check more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb398860(v=vs.100)).
But please note that there is slight difference between ASP.Net Web Pages being compiled at runtime then just your API loading more dll's.
Since you have a SPA framework you shouldn't have any need for web pages pre-compilation.

You could check also those resources:

[SO Question about warmup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019317/how-to-ensure-api-is-warmed-up-before-first-request)

[Blog Post - slightly more advanced](https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/developer-faster-warmup)

But so sum it up - initial "delay" after application startup is a common problem :)